# Problem typesetting a Prisoner's Dilemma table

Tags: tables, multirow

I am going to create a table, which should look like The Prisoner's Dilemma, but I can't create it.

It should look like this:
[image]

My preamble look like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc} 
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx,multirow,tabularx,booktabs}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\def\mathbi#1{\textbf{\em #1}}
\newcommand{\transp}{^{\mathsf{T}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
     \begin{center}
      \caption{The Prisoner’s Dilemma}
     \begin{tabular}{c | c | c |}
     &Factor1&Defect\\\hline%
     Factor2&5&4\\
     Defect&2&2\\\hline
     \end{tabular}
     \end{center}
     \end{table}

\end{document}
```

And the table look like this:

[image]

Can someone tell me how to make the first table with AND without the extra box? The cells should be the same size.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With TikZ it is far simpler:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[element/.style={minimum width=1.75cm,minimum height=0.85cm}]
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,nodes={element},column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,]{
         & Factor 1  & Factor 2  \\
Factor 1 & |[draw]|5 & |[draw]|4 \\
Factor 2 & |[draw]|2 & |[draw]|2 \\    };

\node[draw,element, anchor=west,label={above:\textbf{Name 3}}] at ($(m-2-3)!0.5!(m-3-3)+(1.25,0)$) {5}; % setting the node midway to cell 4 and cell 2 with a horizontal shift of 1.25cm

\node[above=0.25cm] at ($(m-1-2)!0.5!(m-1-3)$){\textbf{Name 1}};
\node[rotate=90] at ($(m-2-1)!0.5!(m-3-1)+(-1.25,0)$){\textbf{Name 2}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The version within `article`

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{bla bla bla}
\label{bla}
\begin{tikzpicture}[element/.style={minimum width=1.75cm,minimum height=0.85cm}]
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,nodes={element},column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,]{
         & Factor 1  & Factor 2  \\
Factor 1 & |[draw]|5 & |[draw]|4 \\
Factor 2 & |[draw]|2 & |[draw]|2 \\    };

\node[draw,element, anchor=west,label={above:\textbf{Name 3}}] at ($(m-2-3)!0.5!(m-3-3)+(1.25,0)$) {5}; % setting the node midway to cell 4 and cell 2 with a horizontal shift of 1.25cm

\node[above=0.25cm] at ($(m-1-2)!0.5!(m-1-3)$){\textbf{Name 1}};
\node[rotate=90] at ($(m-2-1)!0.5!(m-3-1)+(-1.25,0)$){\textbf{Name 2}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

> **Explanation**

A TikZ matrix is simply a node and as every node some anchors become available: incidentally this helps a lot in positioning other elements in the picture.

The first step is to give a name to the matrix: it is done through the syntax `\matrix (m)` where `m` is the name. Using the option `matrix of nodes` then also each cell has a name in the form `<matrix name>-<row>-<column>`.

Since we have a name we can access anchors as `<matrix name>.<anchor>`. But we have to know where these anchors are located. For debugging purposes we can add this code right after the previous `\matrix` definition:

```
% debugging purposes
\draw[red](m.south west)rectangle(m.north east);

\foreach \anchor/\placement in
    {north/above,  south/below, east/right, west/left,
     north west/above, north east/above,
     south west/below, south east/below}
     \draw[shift=(m.\anchor)] plot[mark=x] coordinates{(0,0)} node[\placement=0.15cm]{\scriptsize\texttt{(m.\anchor)}};
```

Now the table looks like:

[image]

In the picture there are two notes: they are added with

```
% Where to put the notes according to what we learnt about matrices
\node[below=0.5cm] at (m.south west) {Note};
\node[below=0.5cm, align=center,text width=5cm] at (m.south) {Another Note which is supposed to be longer};
```

Comment: Thank you very much. When I am trying to run this, the two cells are separated why? And is it possible to include note to the figure?

Comment: @A.F.: I don't have clues about your problem. I used simple TikZ code (no CVS or strange libraries) so it is supposed to run everywhere. For the second question, yes, of course. The document here is a standalone one, but you are free to re-use the code in your real document including the picture into a `table` environment and to add a `caption`.

Comment: The space between Factor 1 and Factor 2 and the cells under "Name 1" is huge. Can I reduce this?

Comment: If I should add footnote and table, can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: @A.F.: sorry, these comments seems to me a "do this for me" questions. For the space between rows, you can open the pgfmanual and look to the `matrix` environment: you will discover how to change row/column separator, even for just one row/column. For the table, see my edit. For the footnotes, see [Footnotes in tables](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=footintab)

Comment: Thank you. I have tried difference options to include a "Note" below the figure, but without any help. It place the "Note" some weird places, that is why I am asking for help. Can you explain me which type I should use and where to put it?

Comment: @A.F.: fine. I will add some more explanation.

Answer (score 13):

You could use `\cline` instructions and use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` in the header row to suppress vertical lines. I've provided some visual formatting hooks (such as `\quad` and `\lower` in the MWE below; I trust you'll manage to figure out how to move the elements around some more using these hooks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2.5} % provide a bit taller rows
\centering
\caption{The Prisoner's Dilemma}
\begin{tabular}{ll | c | c |}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Name1}}\\[-2ex]
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Factor1}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Factor2}\\
\cline{3-4}
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Name2}}}
&Factor1&5&4\\
\cline{3-4}
&Factor2&2&2\\
\cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}
\qquad
\lower3ex\hbox{\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Name3}}\\
\hline
5\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you have two column headers of different widths -- say, `ExtremelyLongHeader` and `LilHeader`-- and if the widths of these headers determine the overall column widths, you could equalize the column widths as follows:

- In the preamble, insert the following instructions:

  ```
  \newcommand\LongestHeader{ExtremelyLongHeader} % replace "ExtremelyLongHeader" with actual header...
  \newlength\mylen
  \settowidth\mylen{\LongestHeader} % \mylen measures width of \LongestHeader
  ```
- ITo set up the `tabular` environment's header, you'd type:

  ```
  \begin{tabular}{ll | c | c |}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Name1}}\\[-2ex]
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\LongestHeader}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\parbox{\mylen}{\centering LilHeader}}\\ % replace "LilHeader" with real column header
  \cline{3-4}
  ...
  ```

  instead of just

  ```
  \begin{tabular}{ll | c | c |}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Name1}}\\[-2ex]
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ExtremelyLongHeader}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{LilHeader}\\
  \cline{3-4}
  ...
  ```

  The `\parbox` command serves to typeset a "paragraph box" of a prespecified width.

Comment: Hi Mico. Thank you for your answer. As you can see I would like to know, how I create the first table, where "Name 1" and "Name 2" exist and where I also have a small box to the right. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Ah, I am sorry, that I didn't express me clear enough. :-) Yes, I would like the "Name 3" as well.

Comment: btw. is it possible to make all sides in the same length (like a square)?

Comment: Thank you very much. I have one question more question - is there any way, so the cells could be exactly the same size? If I change name the cell will change size?

Comment: Hi again Mico.

The last part is confusing me. Can you maybe fill it in the content above, so I can see where the changes are? Is it also possible to add a Note, like this: \multicolumn{6}{@{}l@{}}{\strut\footnotesize Note: Blah blah} - just below the table

Comment: @A.F. - See the revised addendum regarding your first question. On the second question: Given that the table only has four columns, one should probably write `\multicolumn{4}{@{}l@{}}{\strut\footnotesize Note: Blah blah}`.

Comment: \multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \specialcell{Note: Blah blah}} this aint work

Comment: @A.F. - I would like to suggest you post your latest follow-up comment as a *new question*, both because it's substantially unconnected to your original question and because more people will have a chance to see your question and provide answers if you set up a new posting. Also, be sure to state how the macro `\specialcell` is defined.

Answer (score 13):

There is a package for typesetting strategic form games: [`sgame`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sgame), by Martin Osborne.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sgame}

% \renewcommand\gamestretch{2} % double row height

\begin{document}
\begin{game}{2}{2}[\textbf{Name 2}][\textbf{Name 1}]
           & Factor 1 & Factor 2 \\
  Factor 1 & 5        & 4        \\
  Factor 2 & 2        & 2        
\end{game}
\quad
\begin{game}{1}{1}
    & \textbf{Name 3}  \\
    & 1 
\end{game}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]